# Django - site-wide music player

Tags: python, django, asynchronous

I'm trying to incorporate a music player into my Django site. I currently have very basic audio playback with HTML 5, but I want to make it so that music will continue playing while the user browses other pages in the site. I understand this probably means using asynchronous requests, but I'm really not sure where to start since there doesn't seem to be a built-in way for Django to handle it. Where can I start?

Answer (score 1):

Considering putting the player in an [IFRAME](http://support.brightcove.com/en/video-cloud/solutions/embedding-video-cloud-players-iframes)